# Extract number in every line of TSV file

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a file with tab-separated-values and also with blank spaces like this:

```
! (desambiguación)  http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/!_(desambiguación)   5
! (álbum)   http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/!_(álbum_de_Trippie_Redd)    2
!!  http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/!!   4
$9.99   http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/$9.99    6
Tomlinson   http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/(10108)_Tomlinson    20
102 Miriam  http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/(102)_Miriam 2
2003 QQ47   http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/(143649)_2003_QQ47   2
```

I want to extract the last number of every line:

```
5
2
4
6
20
2
2
```

For that, I have done this:

```
while read line;
        do
            NUMBER=$(echo $line | cut -f 3 -d ' ')
            echo $NUMBER
        done < $PAIRCOUNTS_FILE
```

The main problem is that some lines have more spaces than others and `cut` doesn't work for me with default delimiter (tab). I dont' know why, maybe because I am using WSL.

I have tried `cut` with several options but it doesn't work in anyway:

```
NUMBER=$(echo $line | cut -f 3 -d ' ')
NUMBER=$(echo $line | cut -f 4 -d ' ')
NUMBER=$(echo $line | cut -f 2)
NUMBER=$(echo $line | cut -f 3)
```

Hope you can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you really set the delimiter to a tab in your `cut` command? From your posting, it looks as if it were set to a space.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to extract the last number of every line:

You could use `grep`

```
grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+$' file
```

---

Or `mapfile` aka `readarray` which is a bash4+ feature.

```
mapfile -t array < file
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]##* }"
```

Comment: I think the grep version is the simplest and the simplest is the best!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '{print $NF}' file
```

With cut (if it is truly TAB separated and 3 fields per line):

```
cat file | cut -f3
```

If you have some variable number of fields per line, use `rev|cut|rev` to get the last field:

```
cat file | rev | cut -f1 | rev
```

Or with pure Bash and parameter expansion:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    last=${line##*  }    # that is a literal TAB in the parameter expansion 
    printf "%s\n" "$last"; 
done <file
```

Or, read into a bash array and echo the last field:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a arr; do
    echo "${arr[${#arr[@]}-1]}"
done <file
```

If you have a mixture of tabs and spaces you can do what *usually* is a mistake and break a Bash variable on white spaces in general (tabs and spaces) into an array:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    arr=($line)     # break on either tab or space without quotes
    echo "${arr[${#arr[@]}-1]}" 
done <file
```